# Can a mongo query using the $in clause, return results in the same order as in the $in list?

Tags: mongodb

I am using the $in clause within a mongodb query. However, I want my results to be ordered exactly as my input list used in the $in clause.

The results I get back are in the order the objects were inserted.

All the documentation I have read so far tells me that the sort cursor function only works with document fields. Does this mean that I cannot do the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB does not insert in any particular order.  You can sort your results though.

See:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in

```
db.updates.ensureIndex( { ts : 1 } ); // ts == timestamp
var myFriends = myUserObject.friends; // let's assume this gives us an array of DBRef's of my friends
var latestUpdatesForMe = db.updates.find( { user : { $in : myFriends } } ).sort( { ts : -1 } ).limit(10);
```

Comment: Thanks Evan. However in my specific case, the list order of the $in query is derived externally. So, I really want my results sorted in an the same arbitrary order present in the input list. I am trying to retrieve objects based on their ids after the id list is sorted elsewhere.

Comment: You may just want to do that after the fact.  I have found that any complicated sorting is better done in the web layer as it is less expensive than doing it in the database layer.

Comment: Thanks Evan. That is exactly the way I am planning to do it now. Thanks very much for your help.